# Certbot-auto renew failed - The client lacks sufficient authorization - Why?

Tags: certbot

So it's been years i put a certbot-auto certificate for multiple domains on the same server (Apache 2.2 - Debian 7). But today I saw my crontab didn't renew the certificate so I tried to do it in SSH with the followin line :

```
./certbot-auto renew
```

Here is the error statement :

```
    Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/www.domain1.fr.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for domain2.fr
http-01 challenge for domain1.fr
http-01 challenge for www.domain2.fr
http-01 challenge for www.domain1.fr
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert (www.domain1.fr) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/www.domain1.fr.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. domain2.fr (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://domain2.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/ZIp1x0730t7J0iJii67jS95Fli2eLhPA12SgXGzR6P8 [151.80.100.117]: 503, www.domain1.fr (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.domain1.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/hoy1fNZkCyBkK2kA7gQhhW8QpWiCk7K00kFHsxNcZgc [151.80.100.117]: 503, domain1.fr (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://domain1.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/LvfaVWC1VzbOehKgFvJe1gNd3tsEWUH3eBDan1-q8Oo [151.80.100.117]: 503, www.domain2.fr (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.domain2.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/fOAwU_IAvKW7AC9nAFNZ6InVHrYB9VmuB9tGvEGpU2c [151.80.100.117]: 503. Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain1.fr/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain1.fr/fullchain.pem (failure)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: domain2.fr
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://domain2.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/ZIp1x0730t7J0iJii67jS95Fli2eLhPA12SgXGzR6P8
   [151.80.100.117]: 503

   Domain: www.domain1.fr
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.domain1.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/hoy1fNZkCyBkK2kA7gQhhW8QpWiCk7K00kFHsxNcZgc
   [151.80.100.117]: 503

   Domain: domain1.fr
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://domain1.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/LvfaVWC1VzbOehKgFvJe1gNd3tsEWUH3eBDan1-q8Oo
   [151.80.100.117]: 503

   Domain: www.domain2.fr
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.domain2.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/fOAwU_IAvKW7AC9nAFNZ6InVHrYB9VmuB9tGvEGpU2c
   [151.80.100.117]: 503

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
```

I did not change anything about the Vhost configurations or server config so I don't know why certbot don't have autorization to update anymore.

> EDIT :

All domains have an `A` record in `DNS` with the right IP.

My `/.well-known/` folders are currently in 0777 rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an alternativ solution but I did not solve the problem.

I did the tricks like [here](https://www.skymac.org/Admin-Dev/article-40b92f3e-Erreur-Certbot-The-client-lacks-sufficient-authorization-Invalid-response-from.htm) :
I used the following command :

```
./certbot-auto certonly -d www.domain1.fr -d domain1.fr -d domain2.fr -d www.domain2.fr
```

My certificates are now working again.

So the problem (i suppose) is the way `certbot-auto renew` match the webroot of each website.

Thank you very much @Martin Zeitler for you help and your time.

Answer (score 7):

In our case, our DNS was working fine but were still receiving the `lacks sufficient authorization` error.

Finally came across a resource here:
https://webdock.io/en/docs/webdock-control-panel/common-certbot-errors

That brought to light running:

```
certbot rollback
```

Followed by:

```
certbot renew
```

And we were finally able to renew the certificate.

We were seriously on the verge of bringing up a brand new VM and migrating everything over - Because after multiple attempts at solving that issue, the certificate had finally expired and we were in crunch mode.

Maybe this will save someone some grief.

Answer (score 3):

make sure that each of these host-names have an `A` record in `DNS` and that each directory `.well-known/acme-challenge` can be accessed; it could not be any more obvious, when it complains about `503 Service Unavailable`. the log file `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log` might possibly contain further information.

a) on the one domain, `.well-known/acme-challenge` needs to be excluded from URL rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\.well-known/(.*)$
```

b) and on the other one domain, `:80` must not redirect to `:443`.

Comment: Hi, all my domains have an `A` record in `DNS` but in each website folder the `./well-known` folder is empty.

Comment: @Alain.D you need to stop rewriting from `:80` to `:443` ...the second one vhost always switches - and when it serves an expired SSL certificate, this is usually a `500`.

Comment: I did create myself the `acme-challenge` folder in the second domain to make a test. I added the `123` file by myself to see if I can access it by browser.

Comment: @Alain.D updated my answer, because both domains seem to have a rewrite issue.

Comment: what do you mean by "stop rewritting from :80 to :443" ? Should I edit Vhosts configuration and delete all 443 conf lines ?

Comment: @Alain.D this should only be one rule, to be commented out, temporarily... because when I went to `http`, it redirected me to `https`... and the `TLS-SNI` challenge cannot have that.

Comment: This is weird my website are on Prestashop, there is no :80 to :443 in htaccess or Vhost conf

Comment: @Alain.D `non www` is also rewritten to `www`, at least on one of both (or better said four domains, as `TLS_SNI` sees it). one can use the above rewrite condition for all kinds of rewrite rules, no matter if `http` to `https` - or `non www` to `www`... it must be able to serve the file from where it saves it to.

Comment: Well my websites were configured like this a long time ago and since then `Certbot-auto renew` always worked well. IDK why this redirection would be a problem now.

Comment: @Alain.D the refresh probably never worked (at least for the `non www` host-names), because when it redirects before it has the least chance to respond to the incoming challenge, the challenge will not succeed.

Comment: Ok so I checked all `.htaccess` and Vhost conf in `site-enabled` and there is no redirection anymore but right now both website continuent to redirect... Still when I try to renew CERT I get the same error. i'm suspecting my root user doesn't have enough permission to write in /.well-known/ folder or that the /.well-known/ folder certbot tr to match is not in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had updated the `DocumentRoot` for some vhosts in Apache configuration ; thus breaking the LE renewal.

You can check the LE renewal configuration under `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mysite.com.conf`

Those paths under the `webroot_map` section :

```
[[webroot_map]]
mysite.com = /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com
www.mysite.com = /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com
```

Should match the `DocumentRoot` from your Apache vhost configuration

Following my example you can compare using : `grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the nginx-certbot solution

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
sudo certbot --nginx -d xxx.xxx.com
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case it was a newly introduced rule of the organization's Firewall that explicitly blocks the acme-protocol. Hell yeah, it took me several hours of investigation and in the end, I placed such a callenge file in the `.well-known/acme-challenge` folder and tried to load it in the browser. Just to get that page instead:

> Application Blocked
> Access to the application you were trying to use has been blocked in accordance with company policy. Please contact your system administrator if you believe this is in error.
>
> User: MY-IP-ADDRESS
>
> Application: acme-protocol

So when all the other answers could not help you, give it a try and check also for such unpleasant greetings from the network-department.